# How do I use the number of active users of my app with my Cloudant database?

Tags: ibm-cloud, couchdb, cloudant

I have some user documents in my Cloudant database that are updated every time a user logs in to our app.
I'm trying to find how many users logged in within the past 24hrs. What is the best way of achieving this in Cloudant?

Answer (score 2):

Imagine your document looks like this:

```
{
"_id": "abc1234",
"user_id": "xyz567",
"last_login": "2022-11-23T12:00:00.000Z"
}
```

You can create a view keyed on the `last_login` parameter (and select the _count Reducer):

```
function (doc) {
  emit(doc.last_login);
}
```

If you then query that view and supply a `startkey` parameter with the date you want to compare to, you will get the count of users who have logged in since that date, e.g.

`https://mycouchdb.com/userslogin/_design/reports/_view/logybytime?startkey="2022-11-23"`

This will show the number of users who have logged in since November 23, 2022.